# React Typescript and Firebase User Authentication

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

My codes are rendering for user authentication in the login page, but is not protecting the dashboard page. The logout button also doesn't remove credentials from the site. Here is my **App.tsx** code:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline />
      <Box width="100%" height="100%" padding="1rem 2rem 4rem 2rem">
      {/* <Navbar /> */}
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Auth />} />
            <Route path="/dashboard" 
            element={
            <AuthRoute>
              <Dashboard />
            </AuthRoute>} />
            <Route path="/projections"
            element={
            <AuthRoute>
              <Projections/>
            </AuthRoute>} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Box>
  </ThemeProvider>
```

Here is my **AuthRoute.tsx** file:

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export interface IAuthRouteProps {}

const AuthRoute: React.FunctionComponent<IAuthRouteProps> = (props) => {
    const {children} = props;
    const auth = getAuth();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        AuthCheck()
    }, [auth]);

    const AuthCheck = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if (user) {
            setLoading(false);
        } else {
            console.log('unauthorized');
            navigate('/')
        }
    });

    if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>

    return <>{children}</>

};

export default AuthRoute;
```

and my **ProtectedRoute.tsx** file:

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const useAuth = () => {
    const user = getAuth()
    if(user){
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

const ProtectedRoutes = (props:any) => {
    const auth = useAuth()

    return auth?<Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/' />
}

export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

Is wrapping the route paths under **ProtectedRoutes** and incorporating **AuthRoute** at the same time not a good idea?